# How to check if first word of a DataFrame string column is present in a List in Python?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df_sentences` and a List `question_words` as follows:

```
df_sentences:

sentence                         label
you will not forget this movie   0
will the novel ever die          1
why we drink alcohol             1
did trump win the election       1
ambiance is perfect              0


question_words = ['what', 'why', 'when', 'where', 'whose', 'which', 'whom', 'who', 'how', 
                         'do', 'are', 'will', 'did', 'will', 'am', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'can', 'has', 'have']
```

I want to check whether the first word of the `sentence` column is present in the list `question_words` and return the result in a new column `ques_word`.

Expected Output:

```
sentence                         label  ques_word
you will not forget this movie   0      0
will the novel ever die          1      1
why we drink alcohol             1      1
did trump win the election       1      1
the ambiance is perfect          0      0
```

What I tried so far is using `.str.contains('|'.join(question_words)).astype(int)` but as expected it returns all the number of all the substrings that matches with `question_words` list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a fast solution, use a list comprehension.

```
q_set = set(question_words)
df['ques_word'] = [
    1 if w.split(None, 1)[0]  in q_set else 0 for w in df.sentence
]
```

```
df
                         sentence  label  ques_word
0  you will not forget this movie      0          0
1         will the novel ever die      1          1
2            why we drink alcohol      1          1
3      did trump win the election      1          1
4             ambiance is perfect      0          0
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
.str.split(" ")[0].contains('|'.join(question_words)).astype(int)
```

should do the job